# extracting identifiers from row observations

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to extract specific elements, specifically ID, from rows that have NAs. Here is my df:

```
df
ID          x
1-12        1
1-13        NA 
1-14        3
2-12        20
3-11        NA
```

I want a dataframe that has the IDs of observations that are NA, like so:

```
df
ID          x
1-13        NA 
3-11        NA
```

I tried this, but it's giving me a dataframe with the row #s that have NAs (e.g., row 2, row 5), not the IDs.

```
df1 <- data.frame(which(is.na(df$x)))
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic subsetting question:

```
df[is.na(df$x),]
```

Good basic and free guides can be found on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/r/

Cheers
Hannes

Answer (score 1):

Simply run the following line:

```
df[is.na(x),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `complete.cases`

```
subset(df, !complete.cases(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `na.omit`

```
> df[!1:nrow(df) %in% row.names(na.omit(df)), ]
    ID  x
2 1-13 NA
5 3-11 NA
```